# Could using changelogs cause a bottleneck for the app itself?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I have a spring cloud kafka streams application that rekeys incoming data to be able to join two topics, selectkeys, mapvalues and aggregate data. Over time the consumer lag seems to increase and scaling by adding multiple instances of the app doesn't help a bit. With every instance the consumer lag seems to be increasing.

I scaled up and down the instances from 1 to 18 but no big difference is noticed. The number of messages it lags behind, keeps increasing every 5 seconds independent of the number of instances

```
KStream<String, MappedOriginalSensorData> flattenedOriginalData = originalData
                .flatMap(flattenOriginalData())
                .through("atl-mapped-original-sensor-data-repartition", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), new MappedOriginalSensorDataSerde()));


        //#2. Save modelid and algorithm parts of the key of the errorscore topic and reduce the key
        //    to installationId:assetId:tagName
        //Repartition ahead of time avoiding multiple repartition topics and thereby duplicating data
        KStream<String, MappedErrorScoreData> enrichedErrorData = errorScoreData
                .map(enrichWithModelAndAlgorithmAndReduceKey())
                .through("atl-mapped-error-score-data-repartition", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), new MappedErrorScoreDataSerde()));


        return enrichedErrorData
                //#3. Join
                .join(flattenedOriginalData, join(),
                        JoinWindows.of(
                                // allow messages within one second to be joined together based on their timestamp
                                Duration.ofMillis(1000).toMillis())
                                // configure the retention period of the local state store involved in this join
                                .until(Long.parseLong(retention)),
                        Joined.with(
                                Serdes.String(),
                                new MappedErrorScoreDataSerde(),
                                new MappedOriginalSensorDataSerde()))
                //#4. Set instalation:assetid:modelinstance:algorithm::tag key back
                .selectKey((k,v) -> v.getOriginalKey())
                //#5. Map to ErrorScore (basically removing the originalKey field)
                .mapValues(removeOriginalKeyField())
                .through("atl-joined-data-repartition");
```

then the aggregation part:

```
        Materialized<String, ErrorScore, WindowStore<Bytes, byte[]>> materialized = Materialized
                .as(localStore.getStoreName());

        // Set retention of changelog topic
        materialized.withLoggingEnabled(topicConfig);

        // Configure how windows looks like and how long data will be retained in local stores
        TimeWindows configuredTimeWindows = getConfiguredTimeWindows(
                localStore.getTimeUnit(), Long.parseLong(topicConfig.get(RETENTION_MS)));

        // Processing description:
        // 2. With the groupByKey we group  the data on the new key
        // 3. With windowedBy we split up the data in time intervals depending on the provided LocalStore enum
        // 4. With reduce we determine the maximum value in the time window
        // 5. Materialized will make it stored in a table
        stream.groupByKey()
        .windowedBy(configuredTimeWindows)
        .reduce((aggValue, newValue) -> getMaxErrorScore(aggValue, newValue), materialized);
    }

    private TimeWindows getConfiguredTimeWindows(long windowSizeMs, long retentionMs) {
        TimeWindows timeWindows = TimeWindows.of(windowSizeMs);
        timeWindows.until(retentionMs);
        return timeWindows;
    }
```

I would expect that increasing the number of instances would decrease the consumer lag tremendous.

So in this setup there are multiple topics involved such as: 
* original-sensor-data
* error-score
* kstream-joinother
* kstream-jointhis
* atl-mapped-original-sensor-data-repartition
* atl-mapped-error-score-data-repartition
* atl-joined-data-repartition

the idea is to join the original-sensor-data with the error-score. The rekeying requires the atl-mapped-* topics. then the join will use the kstream* topics and in the end as a result of the join the atl-joined-data-repartition is filled. After that the aggregation also creates topics but I leave this out of scope now.

```
original-sensor-data 
\
 \
  \   atl-mapped-original-sensor-data-repartition-- kstream-jointhis -\
  /   atl-mapped-error-score-data-repartition    -- kstream-joinother -\
 /                                                                      \ 
error-score                                          atl-joined-data-repartition
```

As it seems that increasing the number of instances doesn't seem to have much of affect anymore since I introduced the join and the atl-mapped topics, I'm wondering if it is possible that this topology would become its own bottleneck. From the consumer lag it seems that the original-sensor-data and error-score topic have a much smaller consumer lag compare to for instance the atl-mapped-* topics. Is there a way to cope with this by removing these changelogs or does this result in not being able to scale?

Comment: Isn't that a problem of the `consumer group` nature? Independently of the instances number only one consumer can poll from one partition in the topic. Maybe you can increase a number of partitions in your topics and see if that makes some difference when you scale.

Comment: I'm already using 18 partitions so that should cover the scaling requirement or should this be configured also for every individual intermediate topic?

Comment: I think so: for every one

Comment: Checked it and every intermediate topic had also 18 partitions

Comment: Hard to say from 10,000 ft view. Increasing the number of instances should theoretically increase your throughput and fight the lag. I would recommend to tap into JMX metric and try to find out which operator is causing the bottleneck: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/monitoring.html